# Diameter traffic generator

Tags: untagged

I am in a hunt for a Diameter protocol simulator / traffic generator.

It needs to be robust, actively maintained, well documented and portable (Solaris and Linux OS is expected).

The goal is to generate heavy load of requests with a complex AVP structure (3GPP TS 32.299 format), and to stress-test a Diameter Server with the load.

I already checked out Seagull, but it had been discarded because it's not actively maintained (and be frank, it's horribly difficult to use).

Anybody idea?

Answer (score 1):

If you have some budget to spare doing this, I would suggest talking to the folks at Spirent - we are a customer of theirs, our Avalanche box has proved invaluable in the year we have had it.

I am pretty sure they do Diameter - we have only scratched the surface so far with HTTP/S testing.